# Spring portlet mvc init method

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, liferay

i am using spring portlet mvc along with liferay. I need to know if there is a way to call method before all the @ModelAttribute annotations (something like an init method). I need this because i am using object retrieved from db in all the @ModelAttribute methods to extract subset of properties from the object. I am sending the pk-id for the row in the db using request parameter. I don't want to retrieve the object all over again in all the methods annotated with the annotation above (this is slowing down the rendering since i am doing multiple connections to db to retrieve the very same object, which i can do once in an init-like method which should be called before any render/action request). I've tried with @PostConstruct but it throws me an exception, obviously this is not the solution. I don't even know if spring is considering this annotation since it's from the core javax API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Ok, so if you need to call a method before a @(Action/Request) Mapping, you can use an [Interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) from the Spring MVC framework.

This [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?126174-How-to-configure-an-interceptor-in-Spring-MVC-Portlet) might be usefull.

---

Does not answer to your question direclty but I would suggest to create a service to retrieve objects from the DB, and then inject this service in the portlet:

```
@Autowired ServiceDao serviceDao
```

This way you are separating the database access layer with the view layer (controllers should not query the DB directly).

Then to solve you problem could you post some code? If each of your `@ModelAttribute` needs some object from the BD, you can for example retrieve it once and then cache it in your service.

Some resources on [Spring Portlet MVC annotion](http://books.dzone.com/articles/spring-30-portlet-mvc-part-2) that might be usefull.

Comment: i am using liferay service plugin to build my domain. Anyway, i was getting the object through the service, now i created private method in my controller that get's the instance if not already taken, and it stores it as class field. All the @ModelAttribute annotated methods get the object through this private method. This is actually the singleton pattern. Thanks for reply even tough, i need to know if there is any annotation that i can use to make method call before any other @ ModelAttribute or @ (Action/Request)Mapping method.